# Unable to decode pdf received from node api

Tags: reactjs, node.js, pdfkit

I have received successfully generated pdf but unable to open that pdf in my browser here is the component. Is the the correct way to decode blob pdf data received from node api using pdfkit library to generate pdf

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import React from 'react';
import { generatePDFapi } from '../functions/apiCalls';
import data from '../JSONData/data';

export const GeneratePDF = () => {
    const openPDFInNewTab = (pdfData) => {
        console.log("dnfkskjnf", typeof pdfData)
        const pdfBlob = new Blob([pdfData], { type: 'application/pdf' });
        const pdfUrl = URL.createObjectURL(pdfBlob);
      
        const pdfWindow = window.open(pdfUrl, '_blank');
      
        if (!pdfWindow) {
          console.error('Popup blocked. Please allow popups for this site.');
        }
      };

  const handlePDFGenerate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(data);
    
    generatePDFapi(data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("PDF successfully generated", res);
        openPDFInNewTab(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err.message);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="primary" onClick={(e) => handlePDFGenerate(e)}>
        Generate PDF
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```